# Back button cordova

Tags: cordova, back-button

I have a cordova app and I captured the backbutton with this code:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        backPage();
} , false);
```

backPage() is a function to go back in previous page.
Running debug build I see the back page for a moment but then the app goes in pause and the activity disappears. I want that activity doesn't go in pause but it must be visible to the user.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue. Just call

```
navigator.app.overrideButton("backbutton", true);
```

before registering the backbutton-listener. It should work then.

Comment: I tried baut It doesn't work, this si my code: 

navigator.app.overrideButton("backbutton", true);
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
                backPage();
            }, false);

Comment: Is your code inside the `deviceready` callback? - Otherwise it might be, that the overrideButton-code fires too early and does not work.

Comment: I don't remember, maybe yes. I'll try again, thank you